# Is this a circular dependency

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

```
//A.h  
class B;  
class A{  
  void Stuff();
  B* FOO():  
  B* _b;
}  
extern A* A_A();

//A.cpp  
#include "A.h"  
#include "B.h" 
B* A::FOO(){
  return(_b);
} 

//B.h
class B{
 void BOO();
}

//B.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h" 
void B::BOO(){
 A_A->Stuff();
}
```

Here there is a cross include of the .h files from the .cpp files.  So they both depend on one another.  Though using the forward declaration and pointers it seems like that would break the cycle.  So my question is: Is this a circular dependency?  Why?

Comment: I don't see any problem other than A::Stuff not defined. What is your problem?

Comment: Here at work there are some people in my group calling this a circular dependency.  I do not think it is so I want to double check with someone before I speak up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've broken the circular *include* chain with the forward declarations, but you still have a logical circular dependency between A and B.  They each require things provided by the other class.

Regarding your comment above, you should never feel ashamed to bring questions to your team.  If find out you were wrong, then you've learned something.

Answer (score 1):

When `A` depends on `B` and vice versa, you have a circular dependency, by definition. The fact that you can get it to work with a forward declaration doesn't change that fact.